# HTML 5 Web Sockets channels routing

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

I need to create **Web Socket** client connection in format `ws://host:port/route` to be able listen socket messages only from this route and not be able to listen them from, for example `ws://host:port/`.

Now I got a code like this, but it does not work properly:

Client side:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5678/test");
ws.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Connected!");
};

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
};
```

Server side:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    ServerFactory = BroadcastServerFactory

    factory = ServerFactory(u"ws://localhost:5678/test")
    factory.protocol = BroadcastServerProtocol
    listenWS(factory)

    reactor.run()
```

But i'm still able to listen messages from `ws://localhost:5678`.

Are there any mechanism to make **Web Sockets** routing or dividing them by channels?